# How to run Laravel project in browser using VS Code

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I have an existing Laravel project, which I want to run in my browser, using VS Code. How do I do this?

Comment: VS Code is just a code editor afaik, you would still need a local webserver to run it. (e.g. `apache2`, or `php artisan serve`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a built-in terminal in vs code (on a different tab somewhere in the bottom), you can use it to serve your project by a local webserver, with the following command:

`php artisan serve`

After that you can see your project in your browser (localhost:8000 by default).

> Please note this might not work out of the box on Windows.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get my Laravel project to show in my browser. I need to now proceed in debugging this project when it is running in the browser. How do I determine which file in the Laravel project must I place my first Breakpoint so that I can follow the flow of the project?

Comment: It depends on where it crashes, you can see it in the error message.

Comment: It isn't crashing. When I work in Visual Studio, I normally place a Breakpoint in one of the files which is an entry point to the project. This then allows me to follow the flow of the project from that point. I am trying to do the same in this Laravel project in VS Code, but I don't know which file is the entry point of the project. Placing a Breakpoint in the index.php file isn't doing anything?

Comment: The entry point of the application is `public/index.php`, I recommend checking the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/lifecycle

Comment: You can stop execution with this function: `dd($foo)`. Check this question on breakpoints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501077/phpstorm-unable-to-set-breakpoints-in-blade-php-files

Comment: Ok, so I had that right. I guess the next logical questions is: How do I use VS Code to follow the project flow from index.php? Do I place a Breakpoint somewhere in this file? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Apologies, only saw your comment on dd($foo). I will check it out.

Comment: You won't really see the thread with that one. If you want to follow the thread, start at public/index.php and follow the classes and methods that are called from there.

Comment: Ok, more specifically. What is the correct procedure to run VS Code's Debugger? I have installed the extension called "PHP Debug". I don't understand how to use VS Code's Debugger.

Comment: I think you will need a laravel package like this to debug in depth: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. Or find a laravel debugger extension in VS Code (if exists)

Comment: Ok, will investigate that further. Thank you.